# concatenate values from the same tags separated with / in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

My XML is:

```
<_path>
      <objekttyp level="0" parent-level="3">
        <_system_object_id>252</_system_object_id>
        <_global_object_id>252@33a8cae1-a9fa-4655-8c3d-b71241bbc99b</_global_object_id>
        <_uuid>4c5b995c-32b5-45c0-8ad4-8f5c3964bcdb</_uuid>
        <_id>220</_id>
        <_objecttype>objekttyp</_objecttype>
        <_standard>
          <de-DE>ertgretgere</de-DE>
        </_standard>
      </objekttyp>
      <objekttyp level="1" parent-level="2">
        <_system_object_id>486</_system_object_id>
        <_global_object_id>486@33a8cae1-a9fa-4655-8c3d-b71241bbc99b</_global_object_id>
        <_uuid>622dd5f3-a778-4eb4-8d21-531263727772</_uuid>
        <_id>391</_id>
        <_objecttype>objekttyp</_objecttype>
        <_standard>
          <de-DE>regtetr</de-DE>
        </_standard>
      </objekttyp>

    </_path>
```

I need to extract every <_system_object_id> and concatenate them all separated through / . I've already tried two following options, but it doesn't work. 
`This is the result <dc:ispartof>252486</dc:ispartof>`

```
<dc:ispartof>
          <xsl:for-each select="/_path"/>

<xsl:value-of select="_system_object_id" separator="'/'"/>  

        <xsl:value-of select="concat(_system_object_id,'/',_system_object_id)"/>     
        </xsl:for-each>

     </dc:ispartof>
```

Comment: This is the result of my both efforts <dc:ispartof>252486</dc:ispartof>, but I want one slash between such as 252/486

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an XSLT 2 or higher processor and `version="2.0"` or higher in your stylesheet then doing `<xsl:value-of select="//_system_object_id" separator="/"/>` should do, independent of the template you place that `xsl:value-of` in.

Inside your `<xsl:for-each select="/_path"/>` you could use above suggestion or if you want a relative path then `<xsl:value-of select="objekttyp/_system_object_id" separator="/"/>` should select the elements in your sample input.